All syllogism is addressed to that within the soul: Did Aristotle really said that?

All syllogism and therefore a fortiori demonstration, is addressed not to outward speech but to that within the soul.

Did Aristotle really said that, and if so, where?
The claim that he did is in I. M. Bochenski, A History of Formal Logic (Translated and edited by Ivo Thomas, 1961). With no reference, though.
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

You have to read the Refernces (specifically, to para 10.08, page 46): it is An.Post, 76b24 that in J.Barnes' translation (Complete Works, Princeton UP) sounds: "For demonstration is not addressed to external argument—but to argument in the soul—since deduction is not either. For one can always object to external argument, but not always to internal argument."

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks!

The reference is Bocheński, A History of Formal Logic p. 46:

10.08 All syllogism and therefore a fortiori demonstration, is addressed not to outward speech but to that within the soul.
At the same time it must be said that he attaches great importance to the 'outward speech', since he elaborates a well-developed theory of logical syntax and many points of semantic interest. All this teaching, which is next to be considered, warrants the conclusion that the practice of Aristotelian logic was undoubtedly to regard meaningful words as its subject-matter.

Ibid. p. 542 gives the exact reference for 10.08:

An. Post. A 10, 76b24 f.

-tip Mauro ALLEGRANZA
